# Does tec1-12706 work reverse?

Tags: sensor, component-selection

Is it possible if i connect one side of this sensor to hot surface and another one to a heat sink or something cold after that it gives current? 
I have a very hot surface about 300 (C) and want to recharge a battery or use it to supply my circuit in emergency time. Maybe i should use more than 10 tec1 sensor to receive enough current.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are [Peltiers](https://tetech.com/peltier-thermoelectric-cooler-modules/high-temperature/) rated at 200 degrees C, most are only rated for around 80 degrees C.

Peltiers generate power from heat flowing through them, so if you add some material in series thermally you can probably reduce the hot side temperature so that it is within limits. Just having the Peltier there (and the attendant heat sink and/or fan to keep the cold side cold enough to get a big differential) may suck enough heat out to cool your hot surface.

Peltiers represent a low thermal impedance so the heat flow through them for a small temperature differential is considerable- and they are also **very** low efficiency  (a few percent at best) in how well they turn that heat flow into electricity.

You might do better using a conventional heat engine such as a Stirling engine to drive a small generator (such as a permanent magnet motor used in reverse).

[image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score 2):

This Peltier device has limits of 100'C because the ignot material (BiSn) melts at 138'C. With this constrain and ideal heat-exchangers it can produce a maximum power with a 70'C differential.  They are delicate devices so the datasheet limits and rules must be followed.

https://www.google.ca/search?client=firefox-b&dcr=0&ei=OyUPWqvdEenZjwTPkZyADQ&q=tec1-12706+generator&oq=tec1-12706&gs_l=psy-ab.1.2.0i71k1l4.0.0.0.257919.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1..64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.CUXcKJTFB_k